# Earliest version of a freelance assassin getting an assignment from a handler

Tags: first-appearance

Following a John Wick binge, I've realized how used to the idea of freelance assassins getting sent assignments or bounties from some sort of guild and/or personal agent. We saw that in *Hitman (2007)* and *Hitman: Agent 47 (2015)*, both based on the video game *Hitman: Codename 47 (2000)*, where the main character "[is shown to be working for the covert International Contract Agency (ICA) under his handler Diana Burnwood.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman_(franchise))"

Then I happened to watch *Gross Pointe Blank (1997)*, where freelance assassin Martin Blank again gets assignments from a handler he mostly interacts with by phone.

So there's a long history of hitmen, ninjas, and other freelance thugs in movies and TV, but how early do we get this idea of a freelance killer remotely getting assignments, as opposed to, say, getting a personal call from a mob boss?